# How to check for # of lines using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Example: a div with width of 30px with the words "this is text".  Let's say that, since the width is narrow, it renders on the page like this:

this
is
text

(3 lines).  Is there a way in jQuery to tell how many lines it takes to render to the page?  For example, something like, `$("#container").lineCount()`.

Business purpose: if my content exceeds a certain number of lines, I want to manipulate it so that a scroll bar does not appear, but I also have a fixed height, so I don't want to mess with overflow css prop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is tricky but can be done, even if there is no specified line-height or other style. It does involve a bunch of moving parts.

First, build a "sacrificial" container `<div>`. Fill it with a known number of lines of text, one character each, and position it far off-screen:

```
// calculate height per line
$calcdiv = $('<div/>').css({
  width: '50px',
  position: 'absolute', // don't affect layout
  left: '-2000px' // position far off=screen
}).html('A<br />B<br />C<br />D<br />E'); // add five lines

$('body').append( $calcdiv ); // make the browser render it

var lineHeight = $calcdiv.height()/5; // average height per line
```

Now we know the approximate height of a line, in pixels, as rendered by this browser. We turn our attention to the box to be measured:

```
$origDiv = $('div#div_to_measure');
$measureDiv = $origDiv.clone(); // clone it
$measureDiv.css({
  position: 'absolute',
  left: '-1000px', // position far off-screen
  height: 'auto' // let it grow to its natural full height
});
$('body').append( $measurediv ); // add it to the DOM, browser will render it
```

...and now we know the approximate number of lines in the box if allowed to attain its natural dimensions as rendered by the browser:

```
var numLines = $measureDiv.height() / lineHeight;
```

We have to `clone()` because the original box to be measured may have its height restricted by the current page styles and layout.

Now some cleanup:

```
$calcdiv.remove();
$measureDiv.remove();
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/FuWue/

Comment: I know this is an old post, but thanks.  This totally helped me on a current project.  Also, for each `$calcdiv` and `$measureDiv`, I added `css` properties for `font-size`, `font-family`, `font-weight`, and `line-height` set to the original div's props.