# Separately processing wrapped lines using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, word-wrap

I am looking for a way to separately process the lines in a <div> that are wrapped due to a narrow width. That is, if my text is "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem \n ipsum dolor sit amet" and it is seen as below:

Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet lorem
ipsum dolor sit 
amet

Then I should be able to encapsulate each 'line' in a, say, <span> tag, such as:

<span id="line0">Lorem ipsum dolor<span>
<span id="line1">sit amet lorem</span>
... etc.

Edit: We can assume that the width and height of the div is fixed and known.

I couldn't find a proposed solution, if any exists; although there is a good suggestion for **counting** the lines for a fixed line-height: [How to check for # of lines using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492770/how-to-check-for-of-lines-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with this:

```
<div class="narrow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

css:

```
.narrow {
   width:60px;   
}
```

Insert some placeholders where there are spaces:

```
$('.narrow').html($('.narrow').html().replace(/ /g,"<span class='count'> </span>"))
```

Determine the y-position of each placeholder:

```
$('.narrow .count') .each(function() {
     var myPos = $(this).position()
     alert(myPos.top)   
})
```

From there you should be able to figure out where the start/end points of each line based on its y-position.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that seems doable and elegant. I also just found a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738490/finding-line-wraps  
I will try your and Inaimathi's suggestions. Thanks again.